# Jsf composite component not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component, mojarra

I am getting "/pages/addressBook.xhtml @171,105  Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/compositeComponents, but no tag was defined for name: mailInputText" error.

here is my xhtml;

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:bzn="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/compositeComponents"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

 //some stuff  

 <bzn:mailInputText id="mailInputId"                                           
                                       value="#{addressBookController.selectedContact.electronicMail}"/>
```

here is my composite component:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"      
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<composite:interface>       

    <composite:attribute name="id"/>
    <composite:attribute name="value"/>
    <composite:attribute name="required" required="false" default="false"/>

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <p:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
                 value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                 required="#{cc.attrs.required}">
        <f:validateRegex
            pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
    </p:inputText>

</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: What is the file name in which composite component is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon.jar causing this problem. I removed it from libs and now It's working perfectly.